# flush_rewrite_rules() cancels the effect of add_rewrite_rule()

Tags: rewrite-rules

As one of my plugin's features, I'm trying to define a custom url structure, like `http://www.mysite.tld/foo/{action}`. I'm using `add_rewrite_rule()` along with `flush_rewrite_rules()` on plugin activation, which works as expected.

Until `flush_rewrite_rules()` gets called again, during another request, either by hand or by enabling another plugin that does so. When this happens, my rewrite rule suddenly disappears (I'm using [Rewrite Rules Inspector](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to check this).

The minimum code needed to reproduce the issue is this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: PluginA
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'PluginA_activation');

function PluginA_activation()
    {
    add_rewrite_tag('%foo%','([^&]+)'); 
    add_rewrite_rule('foo/([^/]+)','index.php?foo=$matches[1]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite rules are stored in an option. When `flush_rewrite_rules()` is called, this option is removed, WordPress collects all rules registered during the *current request* and writes that option new into the database.

You registration doesn’t run on every request, so it doesn’t exist, when the option is rewritten.

Register the rule on ever page load, flush the rewrite rules on activation. Separate the registration and the flush.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'PluginA_activation');
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'PluginA_rewrite_rules' );

function PluginA_activation()
{
    PluginA_rewrite_rules();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function PluginA_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%foo%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('foo/([^/]+)','index.php?foo=$matches[1]','top');  
}
```

Comment: I see. Would `init` be the most appropriate action for the rule registration? I'm asking because AFAIK `init` runs after plugin activation.

Comment: @geomagas `init` happened already when the plugin is activated. See my update.

Comment: If calling `flush_rewrite_rules` clears the option in the database, then why do you call `flush_rewrite_rules` after `PluginA_rewrite_rules` and not before?