# Hooking "delete_option_rewrite_rules" for rewrite rule addition

Tags: rewrite-rules

**See 2015.07.24 and 2017.01.25 Updates Bellow...**

---

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to ensure my word press "rewrite rules" are set correctly in the event that another plugin calls the `flush_rules()` function.

Traditionally I've seen instructions on adding the rules on every page load of your plugin (eg [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/133906/flush-rewrite-rules-cancels-the-effect-of-add-rewrite-rule))

```
add_action('wp_loaded','define_rules_here');
function define_rules_here()
{
  add_rewrite_rule($foo,$bar,$yams);
}
```

My concern is the way I've written my plugin is the rewrite rules are configurable by the user, and that having to load the options from the database for every page load seems inefficient.

I've found little information on the following, but it seems just as valid...

```
add_action('delete_option_rewrite_rules','define_rules_here');
function define_rules_here()
{
  add_rewrite_rule($foo,$bar,$yams);
}
```

What I've found is that the first thing `flush_rules()` calls is `delete_option('rewrite_rules');` which seems to trigger my hook quite nicely as the `delete_option` function ends with a `do_action( "delete_option_$option", $option );` call.

My question is: Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this approach of hooking into the "delete_option_rewrite_rules" action?

---

**Update 2015.07.24:**

Using `delete_option_rewrite_rules` is bad because it's not fired off if the option has been deleted via some other means, instead I have hooked `delete_option` with the `$option` parameter because its *ALWAYS* fired off prior to option delete unlike `delete_option_*` which is conditional based on the database result.

```
add_action('delete_option','handle_deleted_option');
function handle_deleted_option($option)
{
  if($option === 'rewrite_rules')
  {
    define_rules_here();
  }
}
function define_rules_here()
{
  add_rewrite_rule($foo,$bar,$yams);
}
```

---

**Update 2017.01.25:**

You should also add support for `add_action('update_option','handle_deleted_option');` as wordpress changed re-write rules into updating instead of deleting then inserting.

Comment: Are you flushing rules on every page load?

Comment: No I am not, I only call the flush on my plugin activation/deactivation hook, and when the user configuration us updated via my plugins admin page.  What I am interested in is detecting when _other_ plugins call `flush_rules()` to ensure my rules are not dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the option that stores the rewrite configuration to autoload via the 4th argument of `add_option`:

```
add_option( 'my_plugin_option', $my_plugin_options, '', 'yes' );
```

It'll get loaded and cached with the query that already runs on every page load, so it's a non-issue.

Then you can add your rewrite rules on the correct hook, which is `init`, and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: So ultimately the "wordpress way" of doing things is to have the rewrite rules always read and added via `add_rewrite_rule()` for every page load in the anticipation that something else might call a `flush_rules()`?